# How to i execute application in vc++ that reads data from the installation directory

Tags: c++, winapi

How to execute an .exe from c++ console application. I have try the following methods none have worked.

I want to run a application i have created a while back "Radio.exe". this application reads an xml file at startup, if I manually run this application it works fine, but if run it via console application "Radio.exe" cant find the xml file?

```
void execute( char* path)
{
    // cant find xml ?
    ShellExecuteA( NULL, NULL, path, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW );

    // cant find xml ?
    ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, path, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    // and also cant find xml ?
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO rSEI ={0};
    rSEI.cbSize=sizeof( rSEI );
    rSEI.lpVerb= NULL;
    rSEI.lpFile= "C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\Radio.exe"; //  = path
    rSEI.lpParameters= 0;
    rSEI.nShow = SW_NORMAL;
    rSEI.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    ShellExecuteEx( &rSEI );
}
```

Comment: Is the XML file in the same directory? How does `Radio.exe` search for the file?

Comment: You can either set the working dir ([as Jason says](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11830667/588306)) or change Radio.exe to not rely on the unreliable working/current directoy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set your working directory, lpDirectory:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx

You should probably set this up to be path relative too so you don't have to provide an absolute path.

Example:

- C:\projects\Radio
- C:\projects\Radio\radio.exe
- C:\projects\Radio\radio.xml

Assuming your program, which spawns radio.exe, is in the projects directory. YOu can provide the Radio directory as the relative path.